# Calculate md5 from werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage without saving the object as file

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask for uploading files.
In order to prevent storing same file twice, I'm intending to calculate md5 from the file content, and store the file as . unless the file is already there.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        #next line causes exception
        img_key = hashlib.md5(file).hexdigest()
```

Unfortunatelly, hashlib.md5 throws the exception:

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not FileStorage
```

I've already tried file.stream - same effect.

Is there any way to get md5 from the file without saving it temporarily?

Comment: hmm.. i think filestorage uses already a temporary file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`request.files['file']` is of type `FileStorage` which has a `read()` method.
Try doing:

```
file = request.files['file']

#file.read() is the same as file.stream.read()
img_key = hashlib.md5(file.read()).hexdigest()
```

More info on `FileStorage`: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage

Comment: Thank you! I'm a python beginner. Now it seems so obvious.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, after calling file.read() the file seems to become empty. So, after calling file.save() I get files with 0 content.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: rewind the file pointer with `file.seek(0)`.

Comment: I'd do this in chunks to not read the whole thing into memory just to calculate the MD5.

Answer (score 2):

From the Flask docs

> files
>
> A MultiDict with files uploaded as part of a POST or PUT
>   request. Each file is stored as FileStorage object. It basically
>   behaves like a standard file object you know from Python, with the
>   difference that it also has a save() function that can store the file
>   on the filesystem.

If it's the same as a file object you should be able to do this

```
img_key = hashlib.md5(file.read()).hexdigest()
```